# Applying filters to get-file in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to use get-file function to show files only of one extension for user to choose from. However, I am not able to apply filters to get-file function http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=get-file#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._get-file%29%29

I have tried:

```
(get-file "*.txt")
(get-file [filters "*.txt"])
(get-file '(("*.txt")))
(get-file '("*.txt"))
(get-file (list (list "TxtFiles" "*.txt")))
etc
```

But it does not work. What is the proper method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
(get-file #f #f #f #f #f null '(("txt file" "*.txt")))
```